# Why am I getting the error: "Error while executing command: dotnet publish"?

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-codebuild

I created the **buildspec.yml** file to use in **AWS CodeBuild** and am getting the error below when I run it:

> COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: dotnet
> publish -c release -o build/outputs/Host. Reason: exit status 1

I already check the path I'm passing in the '-o' parameter, I've even removed it, but I keep getting the error.

I am using **dotnet 5.0**. Do I need to install it before I build it? If yes, how can I do this?

**Below I put the snippet that matters from my buildspec.yml:**

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      docker: 18
  
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo pre-build started on `date`
      - echo Logging in to Amazon ECR...
      - aws ecr get-login-password --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com
      
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Building dotnet API...
      - cd aspnet-core/src/SITR.Web.Host
      - echo Executing dotnet restore...
      - dotnet restore
      - echo Executing dotnet publish...
      - dotnet publish -c release -o ../../../docker/build/outputs/Host
  
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Pushing the Docker image...
      - docker-compose --file=docker-compose-qa.yml push
      - echo Build completed on `date`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dotnet: 5.0` is supported only in [dotnet](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/runtime-versions.html) run-time. But you are using docker runtime. So either you have to change your runtime, or manually setup/install dotnet in your run-time.

Comment: Your answer helped me to reach the solution, I accepted it as an answer and soon post another answer with the solution I set up to be able to use .net5.0 and docker.

Answer (score 0):

[Marcin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/248823/marcin)'s response helped me to come up with the solution. I'm recording in another answer what I needed to do, maybe it will help someone else.

For my build I need to use **dotnet 5**, **nodejs (npm)** and **docker**.

The problem is that I was using **Amazon Linux 2** and according to [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/available-runtimes.html) ***dotnet 5 is only available in Ubuntu 5.0 for now***.

Initially I was still a little confused, because I thought I would need to install the docker, but actually it is already installed in the ubuntu 5.0 image. To test this I **edited my CodeBuild and changed the version to Ubuntu 5.0** and ran my buildspec with `docker --version` command as below and checked the logs.

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      dotnet: 5.0
      nodejs: 14
    commands:
      - docker --version
```

Basically I needed to switch to Ubuntu 5.0 version and my buildspec.yml looked like this:

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      dotnet: 5.0
      nodejs: 14

  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo pre-build started on `date`
      - echo Logging in to Amazon ECR...
      - aws ecr get-login-password --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com
      
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Building dotnet API...
      - cd aspnet-core/src/SITR.Web.Host
      - echo Executing dotnet restore...
      - dotnet restore
      - echo Executing dotnet publish...
      - dotnet publish -c release -o ../../../docker/build/outputs/Host
  
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Pushing the Docker image...
      - docker-compose --file=docker-compose-qa.yml push
      - echo Build completed on `date`
```